# Он даёт привыкнуть к нему или себе?

Tags: местоимения

В таком предложении:

> Он заходит справа и, поравнявшись, даёт ей немного привыкнуть к себе.

как правильно: к нему или к себе? Меня смущает "себе", потому что можно подумать, что он даёт ей время привыкнуть к себе же самой. Хоть это и нелогично. Какое грамматическое правило существует?

Comment: Сказать двусмысленно — не сказать ничего. То есть, это ошибка в сообщении (предложении). В дисциплинах математика и логика мы используем правила (до**вер**яем правилам), чтобы про**вер**ить вычислением, однозначно ли принятое сообщение. Но люди-читатели не используют явно правила грамматики. Следовательно, на явные правила грамматики, для разрешения двусмысленности, не может полагаться и писатель. Отсюда, если есть сомнения в однозначности, то необходим не поиск правила грамматики для расшифровки или написания, а переформулирование, устраняющее всякую двусмысленность.

Comment: @Avtokod - То есть, вы хотите сказать, что в предложении «даёт ей немного привыкнуть к себе» есть некая двусмысленность? Вы часто давали людям возможность, чтобы они привыкли к себе?

Comment: @YellowSky, Да. Для местоимения `себе` здесь два антецедента, что есть ошибка составителя предложения. (1) *ей к себе;* (2) *[он] к себе.* [Поиск](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%22) дает много результатов как ответ на вопрос «что делает?», думаю, это достаточно убедительно, что в каком-то случае представится  возможность дать «вот это сделать».

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Грамматическое правило простое: местоимения  `себя, себе, собой`, не имеющее именительного падежа, а также `свой` означают того же, кто является *подлежащим* в передложении.

> Он увидел себя. - Значит «Х увидел Х», т. е. субъект и объект тождественны.
>
> Он увидел его. - Значит «Х увидел Y», т. е. субъект и объект различныны.
>
> Он взял свою сумку. - Значит «Он взял сумку, принадлежащую ему же».
>
> Он взял его сумку. - Значит «Он взял сумку, принадлежащую другому мужчине, чужую сумку».

Поскольку в вашем предложении «Он даёт ей привыкнуть к себе» подлежащим является «он», то «себе» тут может означать только то же, что и «он»: «он даёт ей привыкнуть к нему же самому». Если бы мы сказали «Он даёт ей привыкнуть к нему», то это бы означало «Он даёт ей привыкнуть к другому [мужчине]», как, например в такой ситуации: «Светлана не любит собак, а Олег купил щенка, поэтому пока что они [Светлана и Олег] выгуливают его [щенка] вместе, он [Олег] даёт ей [Светлане] привыкнуть к нему [к щенку]».

Ещё лучше эту разницу видно в творительном падеже:

> Он разговаривал с собой. — Он разговаривал с ним.

Хотя в первом предложении перед «собой» ещё можно было бы добавить слово «самим», но и без него разница очень хорошо видна.

Comment: Круто! Всё по полочкам разложили. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: По вашей логике, «*он просил её ни в чем себе не отказывать*» подразумевает, что она не должна отказывать ему же, поскольку *он* - подлежащее?

Comment: @J-mster - Хороший вопрос, спасибо. _«Ни в чем себе не отказывать»_ – это устойчивое выражение, означающее «жить на полную, тратить сколько угодно», оно всегда употребляется в таком виде, если заменить там «себе» на какое-либо другое местоимение, то значение этой фразы изменится радикально: _«Ни в чем ему не отказывать»_ значит «всячески ему помогать, исполнять все его желания». Есть и другие устойчивые выражения с «себе, себя», например «Ничего себе!», «представлять себе», «корчить из себя», и т. д., все они всегда употребляются только с «себе, себя», никогда с другими местоимениями.

Comment: Идея верная, но анализ предложения - нет. Местоимение "себе" в примере "Он дает ей привыкнуть к себе" может контролироваться и подлежащим главного глагола ("он"), и нулевым подлежащим инфинитива ("она"), поэтому и значений может быть два.

Comment: @Olga - Конечно же, привыкать к себе – это то, чем все мы постоянно занимаемся, я вот вчера к себе привык, а сегодня ещё не успел, сейчас вот комментарий допишу и опять к себе привыкнуть попробую. Вопрос ведь был не о том, что значит «Он дает ей привыкнуть к себе», а о том, как правильно выразить ту мысль, которую автор хотел донести.

Comment: @YellowSky я указываю на ошибку в вашем объяснении. Вы пишите, что "Поскольку в вашем предложении «Он даёт ей привыкнуть к себе» подлежащим является «он», то «себе» тут может означать только то же, что и «он»". Это неверно. "себе" может относится и к субъекту главного глагола "он", так и к субъекту инфинитива "она".

Answer (score 3):

The question is not that simple. The "Introduction to Common Syntax" of Tyestyelec has half of the fifth (or maybe sixth, I'm not sure) chapter about such things. "Себя" and "свой" inside the infinitive clause correspond to the zero-subject of the infinitive clause, which doesn't have to correspond to the subject but can also correspond to other objects of the main verb in certain situations.

The sentence "даёт ей немного привыкнуть к себе" can therefore mean "к ней же", and it is semantics not syntax that stops us from such an understanding in usual situation.

Comment: So I thought.... So what do you suggest? Is there any way to restructure this sentence and keep the meaning?

Comment: If you desperately need this, you can say "к самому себе" - luckily he and she have different gender.